# Adding <div>'s on the user login page

Tags: users, forms

The following code is adding `<div>`'s and link to the form action. How can I add them before the form?

```
function ajax_register_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['bigletters'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'Big letters',
  );

  $form['smallletters'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'Small letters',
  );

  $form['links'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => '<a href="http://example.com"></a>',      
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the form elements you are adding to appear before the other ones, you should use the [#weight](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval) property, and give them a negative value, since the default value is zero. Differently, the form elements you add to a form via `hook_form_alter()` are normally appended to the form, with the exception of when there is a form element with a positive #weight value higher than the #weight value you assigned to your form element.

[user_login()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login/7) doesn't set the weight of its form elements. The following code should work.

```
function ajax_register_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['bigletters'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'Big letters',
    '#weight' => -10,
  );

  $form['smallletters'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'Small letters',
    '#weight' => -8,
  );

  $form['links'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => '<a href="http://example.com"></a>',      
    '#weight' => -6,
  );
}
```

If the code doesn't work, then there is probably another module that alters the weight of the other form elements.

Comment: this solution worked, but can i somehow post it out of form?

Comment: You cannot, since with `hook_form_alter()` you are altering a form. To add something outside a form, you should alter the page output, for example with [hook_page_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), but I don't see any reason to write more complicate code. If the problem is targeting some HTML elements, you can use a different CSS selector.

Comment: you right. i made it with css. thx again!

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, but can you give me an example how to make it with hook_page_alter()?